# Subset arrows in xymatrix

Tags: arrows, xy-pic

Is it possible to make an arrow in xymatrix that is a subset symbol?

Answer (score 9):

I personally use :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix@1{A\, \ar@{}[r]|-*[@]{\subset} & B}
\]

\end{document}
```

It's very simple and I guess it can look weird if the space between entries is too big, but I feel it the best way, enlarged subset symbols are just awful.

Maybe with a little more skill in xy-pic constructions, you can arrange to slightly rescale the symbol depending on the space between entries.
By hand, it's possible for sure, but I guess it would be possible to do that automatically too.

Comment: It seems that the direction of the label `\subset` fits the direction of the arrow. The symbol `*` seems to modify the feature of the label as the meaning of `[@]`.  Could you give some more details about what `[@]` means? I cannot find what it means from `xy-pic_guide.pdf` while `xyrefer.pdf` seems difficult to read...

Comment: Wow, I'm sorry, but I haven't used xypic in the past 4 years: not many commutative diagrams to draw, and I learnt to use tikz in the meantime, so I didn't need to remember the arcane xy syntax.

Answer (score 6):

It's common to represent monomorphisms using an arrow having a subset symbol at the beginning, (as in `amsmth`'s `\hookrightarrow`). The `xy` package offers the `@{^{(}->}` construct for such an arrow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[A\hookrightarrow b\]

\[
\xymatrix@1{A\, \ar@{^{(}->}[r] & B}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Another common picture of an injective morphism is the arrow `\ar@{>->}[r]`

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina, do you know if is possible to make the arrow shorter so the inclusion tail and arrow tip are not so close to the diagram entry?

Answer (score 1):

If you want an extensible subset symbol, you could use the couple of arrows

```
\ar@{^{(}-}[r]\ar@<1ex>@{-}[r]
```